# how can I ensure web client's request data is credible?

Tags: security, web

there need some ‎explaining of the 'credible'.

Scene: I postulate A as my web server, B as third-part server and C as client by Browser.Please read on (I'm sorry, it's difficult present by code)
The C post a request to B(third-part server),B response C with some data and than C post the data to A.
Question: as above postulated, A is my server and how can I ensure client's data is credible.

It seems difficult in web environment because all of the client code could be seen and request also be created by client.
In third-part server support a direct feedback to my server,but there haven't.It means, I will get the data by client, does have some authentication between client and server or other ways to make the data is credible?
Thanks reading.Any advice hope!

Comment: By "credible", you mean that to assure the data came from B and has not been modified by C?  Ideally B would have a public/private key that signs the data sent to C, and then using the public key, A would be able to verify the signature.  A technology such as JWT can contain the data and signature info.  If that is not available, good luck!

Comment: @TheGreatContini thanks, I will check whether there exist usable key. Besides,JWT is a good tools, I will also test it.